# Why does `this` inside filter() gets undefined in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a DOB Form.

I am using VueJS in the form. The user should their date of month first so that day is displayed according to the number of days in the respective month.

I am using `filter()` and the problem is `this` inside `filter()` is undefined. How can I fix this?

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    months: [
      {month: 'January', days: 31},
      {month: 'February', days: 28},
      {month: 'March', days: 31},
      {month: 'April', days: 30},
      {month: 'May', days: 31},
      {month: 'June', days: 30},
      {month: 'July', days: 31},
      {month: 'August', days: 31},
      {month: 'September', days: 30},
      {month: 'October', days: 31},
      {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31},
    ],
    selectedMonth: []
  },
  computed: {
    filterDays() {
      return this.months.filter(function(value) {
        return value.month === this.selectedMonth;
      });
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div class="app">
  <select id="dobd">
    <option v-for="day in filterDays[0].days" :value="day">{{ day }}</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

I know using a global variable might be the solution but I want to use `selectedMonth` inside `data()` due to my own needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `function () {}` the context (`this`) is lost. Which means, inside the `filter` argument function, `this` will not be the Vue instance.

There are some possible solutions:

- Use arrow functions (**preferred**):

  ```js
  filterDays() {
    return this.months.filter((value) => {
      return value.month === this.selectedMonth;
    });
  }
  ```
- Use `.bind()`:

  ```js
  filterDays() {
    return this.months.filter(function(value) {
      return value.month === this.selectedMonth;
    }.bind(this));
  }
  ```
- Use a local variable outside the function:

  ```js
  filterDays() {
    let vm = this;
    return this.months.filter(function(value) {
      return value.month === vm.selectedMonth;
    });
  }
  ```

Demo:

```js
new Vue ({
  el: '.app',
  data: {
    months: [
      {month: 'January', days: 31},
      {month: 'February', days: 28},
      {month: 'March', days: 31},
      {month: 'April', days: 30},
      {month: 'May', days: 31},
      {month: 'June', days: 30},
      {month: 'July', days: 31},
      {month: 'August', days: 31},
      {month: 'September', days: 30},
      {month: 'October', days: 31},
      {month: 'November', days: 30},
      {month: 'December', days: 31},
    ],
    selectedMonth: 'January' // changed to a valid month
  },
  computed: {
    filterDays() {
      return this.months.filter((value) => {
        return value.month === this.selectedMonth;
      });
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div class="app">
  <select id="dobd">
    <option v-for="day in filterDays[0].days" :value="day">{{ day }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `days` is undefined now :(

Comment: That's because you didn't have a valid `this.selectedMonth`. See the demo in the answer (just added).